# Wildcard certificate with separate certificates for each host

Tags: ssl, hosts, ssl-certificate

We're using a wildcard certificate on several hosts, which right now means that we have to distribute the wildcard cert's private key to each machine, which is a security problem. On the other hand, buying a separate certificate for each new host is way too expensive for us.

Is there a way to not have the private key on each host? Can I myself create a certificate for that specific host and sign it with the wildcard certificate, or something along those lines? How is this normally handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most companies will allow unlimited duplicates of a wildcard that use a different csr. Digicert allows unlimited free dupes on their wildcard plus, for example.

You could sign your own certs, but no browsers would have a trust for it so it's a little pointless.

Comment: But that would still make MITM attacks on all our connections possible if just one host is compromised, right?

Comment: Yes. This is the downside with wildcard certificates -- you only have one identity.

Comment: Then I fear that wouldn't really win much for us. Not that we like the thought of having to manually request a certificate from a CA for each host, we create new ones all the time.